# ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait deprecated in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

[image: code screenshot]

So      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait/Landscape has been deprecated in iOS6. There's not much after searching on google. I guess this is too new. I mean, I think I can still run the app, just wondering if anyone knows what Apple is really up to with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS6 came several new updates to the auto-resizing capabilities.  Apple no longer wants developers to use the `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` techniques, and instead use the auto-resizing capabilities of iOS6.

Similarly, the `setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier` and `setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers` are also deprecated.

A pretty good tutorial that I found the other day on auto-resizing in iOS6 can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2/)